# How to check if lottie animation works?

Tags: android, lottie

Im trying to do a simple loading with lottie. I found this animation: https://lottiefiles.com/18563-cooking#_=_

```
  <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/animation_view"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/test"
            />
```

It's stored in SRC/Main/res/raw but I get this error:

> You must set an images folder before loading an image. Set it with LottieComposition#setImagesFolder or LottieDrawable#setImagesFolder

I try to add to assets folder with `app:lottie_fileName`

So I think the animation is bug, because of this I want to know if exist some tools or command to know if animation works.

Answer (score 5):

in my case ,my lottie json file contains code fragment like this:

```json
{  
 "id": "image_0", 
 "w": 1241,
 "h": 802,  
 "u": "images/", 
 "p": "image_01.png",  
 "e": 0
}
```

it means it need image `image_01.png` to work. and it will look for it from folder `images/`.

if you don't provide this images folder location it will throw this exception.

here is the step i solved my problem.

1. add the folder  images into `assets` folder, the folder sturcture:

> ```
> +-assets
>
> +----images
>
> ---------image_01.png
> ```

2. add `app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="images"`in the xml( or

you can add`setImageAssetsFolder("/images");`in code. )

Comment: but how can we get the image from lottie?